# Delete rows from tableview using swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I make a table view on my application, I want to add option that could the user delete the row in tableview.
I'm using this func
h1 is my array string that I put it in tableview. 
my error is when I'm try to delete row in func editinstyle

```
  var h1:[String] = ["one","two","three"]


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        h1.count
}
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell3", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! TableView1

        cell.information.text = h1[indexPath.row]
}
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            print("Deleted")

            h1.remove(at: indexPath.row) //Remove element from your array
            print(h1)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }
```

[image]
when I try to click to Delete it show like this[image: error] 2020-02-11 20:43:35.803024+0200 TraniersApp[13314:401189] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Does someone know where is the problem?

Comment: Can you print `h1` before calling `remove(at:)` to see whether `remove(at:)` actually does anything?

Comment: The code you have shown is correct, but I suspect that it isn't your actual code since the output in the screenshots is different. The exception indicates there is a problem with your `numberOfRows` Function.  Also there appears to be another array `value` involved

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define "[indexPath]". It becomes [IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: 0)]

```swift
tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
```

or

recall the particular section in the table view also

This will work outside of the function

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Answer (score -1):

Suspect this is a race condition that can be resolved by performing the h1.remove() and tableView.deleteRows() within a transaction (i.e., between `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()`).

```swift
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    h1.remove(at: indexPath.row) //Remove element from your array
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: `beginUpdates/endUpdates` has no effect at all for a single `insert`/`delete`/`move` operation.

Comment: @vadian Hmm. I stand corrected. Something else that I've done in the intervening time appears to have corrected the real error that the transaction was masking. I was able to remove the transaction without error. Thanks.